# DomainDataService (ViewModel) loading an entity via a string name

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, reflection, mvvm

So I'm attempting to dynamically load my domain data service where the table name is the string ... Here's what I've got so far:  Normally I'd load like this:

```
 theDomainDataService.Load(theDomainDataService.getUsersQuery());
```

so I'm trying to automate which entity is loaded by the string name.

```
 String theVariableEntityName = "Users";
 Type t = theDomainDataService.GetType();
 MethodInfo stuff = t.GetMethod("Get" + theVariableEntityName + "Query");
 var theQuery = stuff.Invoke(theDomainDataService, null);
 theDomainDataService.Load((EntityQuery<MySite.Web.Models.User>)theQuery);
  ---------------------------------------------------------^ Problem
```

This is in fact loading my domainDataService correctly, but what I need is a dynamic way to infer the type of the EntityQuery (without explicitly declaring it's going to be a User), because in fact it could be anything.

I have tried this from the DomainDataService Class with no luck, it isn't finding method's "Set" or "Entry".

```
    public List<object> void PopulateEntity(string theEntityName)
    {
        Type theEntity = Type.GetType("MySiteMaintenance.Web.Models." + theEntityName);
        using (var db = new DatingEntities()) 
        {                        
              IQueryable query = db.Set(theEntity);
              foreach (var item in query) 
              {
                  var entry = db.Entry(item);
              }
        }
    }
```

Remember, all I need is a populated entity (when all I have is the name of the entity) populated Client side... so I can say

```
 DomainServiceClass theClass = new DomainServiceClass();
 theClass.Load(theClass.GetEntityNameQuery());
```

so I can reference the appropriately loaded entity with...
     theClass.Entity (users... questions, etc..)

Comment: In retrospect, this IS in fact loading the Entity correctly. But I need a way to dynamically specify my "type" (MySite.Web.Models.User) Thoughts? :(

Comment: Can the type (ex: `MySite.Web.Models.User`) be inferred from `((TabItem)sender).Header`? Or is it passed as an argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm still not sure I follow, but...

I have a `Post` entity in my `Sandbox` namespace which I get from my `DbContext` instance using the entity type name in a string to start with...

```
                // Get my entity type (if in same assembly, else you'll have to specify)
                Type postType = Type.GetType("Sandbox.Post");

                using (var db = new StackOverflowEntities()) {                        

                    // not required
                    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

                    IQueryable query = db.Set(postType);
                    foreach (var item in query) {

                        DbEntityEntry entry = db.Entry(item);

                    }
                }
```

Which results in retrieving any DbSet based on a Entity type string.  Below a breakpoint in the item foreach loop - revealing the values.

[image]

Comment: Cannot find method Set. For what it's worth, I'm having to run this code from a domain service class to get access to My entities.

Comment: The Set method is off your DbContext derived class.  Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt I did end up getting the respective entities using this method (I needed the SP1 for EF 4.0 to get access to DbContext).. But what I'm really trying to do is load the entity so that it's available via client side as theViewModel.Entity... does this make sense?

Comment: No i'm afraid i don't :/  If by the time the client consumes the Entity and the client knows the expected type then create a generic method or property to access the value.  If not, just return type object and let the client perform the cast.